# Does Facebook allow user to post feed from an app without dialogue?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, fbsdk, fb-graph

Does Facebook SDK allow publishing a post on a user’s wall through graph API without showing a share dialog window each time from mobile apps?

I am using Facebook Graph API to publish posts from app to user's wall.

Requirement is: Post a feed to fb without showing share dialog each time i.e., ask user's permission only once (for example: this app will post your feeds to fb too) and don't show share dialog for other upcoming posts.

Does Facebook allow this?

During the Facebook login process, can we ask user to grant permissions to post on his behalf on Facebook and post on his wall from application later without share dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question,Facebook does allow users to post feeds from an application to user's wall on facebook wihtout dialogues using graph API.

However, you will need to submit your application for review on facebook. Until this process is not complete, only those people who are marked as developers in project settings of project on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) will be able to see test posts.

Facebook requires you to give users a proper control over sharing on facebook if you are implementing facebook sharing without feed dialog. If you don't meet the criterias laid down by facebook, your application will not be accepted by facebook to use graph API.
Here is a link to Facebook Review principles:  [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/]

Comment: can you please send graph api url here? Also login permission which we require to grant?